# Checking against null in Equals()

Tags: c#

How come if I comment out the second line when overriding Equals() like so:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) {
    if(object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
    //if(obj == null) return false;
    Person other = obj as Person;
    if(other == null) return false;
    return this.Name == other.Name;
}
```

I get a NullReferenceException? If I uncomment it, it'll work. Also I made sure that the obj argument wasn't a null, and it still does that.

Here is full code

```
namespace MyNameSpace{

class Person : IComparable<Person>{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public static bool operator <(Person x, Person y) {
        return x.CompareTo(y) < 0;
    }
    public static bool operator >(Person x, Person y) {
        return x.CompareTo(y) > 0;
    }
    public static bool operator ==(Person x, Person y) {
        return x.Equals(y);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Person x, Person y) {
        return !x.Equals(y);
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if(object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        //if(obj == null) return false;
        Person other = obj as Person;
        if(other == null) return false;
        return this.Name == other.Name;
    }
    public int CompareTo(Person other) {
        return this.Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Person one = new Person("one");
        Person two = new Person("two");

        Console.WriteLine(one == two);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show us full code how you're using it, (including the constructor on the object you're passing in)?

Comment: Is == overloaded? if so try if(object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null)) return true;

Comment: Often it's better to not overload all operators since it just adds confusion.

Comment: @paulpaul1076 Yep, that's the error, replace your commented like with  if(object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null)) return true; or update your overloaded == operator code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have a custom `==` operator on `Person`, which is being invoked by the line:

```
if(other == null) return false;
```

Which also hints that the operator *is buggy* and should be fixed.

Edit: and with your update: here *is* the buggy custom `==` operator:

```
public static bool operator ==(Person x, Person y) {
    return x.Equals(y);
}
```

Using just:

```
public static bool operator ==(Person x, Person y) {
    return Equals(x,y);
}
```

would solve that, along with:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) {
    if(obj == (object)this) return true; // ref equality, the cheap way
    if(obj is Person) {
        Person other = (Person)obj;
        return this.Name == other.Name;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter the operator is from the update question, and is simply buggy; `x.Equals(y)` doesn't work if `x` is `null`.

Comment: However, `other == null` should be omitted. If not NRE, it will throw `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes, personally I would use `object` througout; I'll update to illustrate

Comment: @TimSchmelter it was meant as "I said there was probably a buggy custom `==` operator, and look: with your edit, sure enough, here it is!"

Comment: Anyway, I found the problem and posted my own answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule for `IComparable` implementation, I would strongly recommend [Eric Lippert's approach](http://ericlippert.com/2013/10/07/math-from-scratch-part-six-comparisons/). It's very simple and helps a lot to not get NRE.

Basically, you don't call either `Equals` or `==` in any operator overload. You just call a unique static method that does all the job:

```
public int CompareTo(Natural x) { return CompareTo(this, x); }
public static bool operator <(Natural x, Natural y) { return CompareTo(x, y) < 0; }
public static bool operator >(Natural x, Natural y) { return CompareTo(x, y) > 0; }
public static bool operator <=(Natural x, Natural y) { return CompareTo(x, y) <= 0; }
public static bool operator >=(Natural x, Natural y) { return CompareTo(x, y) >= 0; }
public static bool operator ==(Natural x, Natural y) { return CompareTo(x, y) == 0; }
public static bool operator !=(Natural x, Natural y) { return CompareTo(x, y) != 0; } 
public override bool Equals(object obj) { return CompareTo(this, obj as Natural) == 0; }
public bool Equals(Natural x) { return CompareTo(this, x) == 0; }

// negative means x < y 
// positive means x > y 
// zero means x == y 
// two nulls are equal 
// otherwise, null is always smaller 
private static int CompareTo(Natural x, Natural y) { 
    if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) 
        return 0; 
    else if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) 
        return -1; 
    else if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) 
        return 1; 
    else if (ReferenceEquals(x, Zero)) 
        return -1; 
    else if (ReferenceEquals(y, Zero)) 
        return 1; 
    else if (x.head == y.head) 
        return CompareTo(x.tail, y.tail); 
    else if (x.head == ZeroBit) 
        return CompareTo(x.tail, y.tail) > 0 ? 1 : -1; 
    else 
        return CompareTo(x.tail, y.tail) < 0 ? -1 : 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get it, I was recursively calling operator ==, and at some point i had operator == (x, y), where x and y were both null, and then I did x.Equals(), that's why it threw that exception.

Comment: so basically... exactly what I said?

Comment: @MarcGravell yes, sorry, I didn't notice that because you said it in the comments , I will accept your answer